# Customize apps gallery in appstore page

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I was looking other big companies gallery on appstore on my iPhone. some of them have their logo on top with custom background color. I was wondering how, is it in the settings somewhere ? or we need to approach Apple and pay this.

See below :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

These applications or developers are selected by Apple to be featured on their main page. This isn't a setting that you can control, or even something that you can pay for. The only way to get featured is if Apple thinks that your app is feature-worthy.

That being said, here's an article on how to get your app featured on the App Store: http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/how-to-get-featured-on-the-app-store

Here's another one that you might want to take a look at: http://thenextweb.com/dd/2013/10/29/get-featured-app-store/

Answer (score 2):

The customized artwork has been provided by developers who were editorially selected by Apple and there is no other way to have your page customised. Even having hundreds of apps on the App Store was not enough, hovewer Apple suggests being prepared for the opportunity and having your assets ready.

All the technical details about assets, dimensions and types of files may be found in the document called "App Store Design Specifications" which you can find in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. I never seen this thing before and any settings in iTC to customise this page.

As you said, this must be something specific and for big companies only. There is a contract or something like that that allows them to customise their own page.
To be completely sure, contact the Apple Developers Team or ask in the Developer Forums. Maybe some Apple guy will confirm this.

Comment: Yah, I thought so, maybe apple allows only some selected companies. But, hoping to get solid answer before I contact Apple.