# How do some iOS appstore pages have customized backgrounds and styling?

Tags: ios, app-store

I believe they're selected as editor's choice.  Is the styling something that apple asks you to provide, and is this exclusive to editor's choice apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the vague recollection that things might be changing in iTunesConnect to coincide for iOS 9, but for now the key to get the customized backgrounds & styling [is indeed having your app ***featured***](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/91939-custom-background-in-app-store.html).

And if that magic moment in your app's life does happen, [here is a blog entry that instructs you how to handle the artwork requests](http://blog.cleanshavenapps.com/app-store-promo-artwork-tips-and-sketch-template).

EDIT: and actually, a few moments after I researched the answer to your question, [I found a related (or totally duplicate) version of this same question that's been answered here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749972/customize-apps-gallery-in-appstore-page).